# MobX 6 | React Not Found Function

Tags: reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

MobX 6 sees the 'counter' variable in a react project I set up. But it doesn't see functions(increment, decrement). I have attached the output to the attached picture. What would be the reason?

```
import {observable, computed, action, makeObservable} from 'mobx';

class UserStore {
    counter = 0;

    increment() {
        this.counter++;
    }
    decrement() {
        this.counter--;
    }
    get counterMoreThan10() {
        return this.counter > 10;
    }
    constructor() {
        console.log('constructor')
        makeObservable(this, {
            counter: observable,
            increment: action,
            decrement: action,
            counterMoreThan10: computed
        });
    }
}
const store = new UserStore();
export default store;
```

```
import React from 'react';
import {inject, observer} from "mobx-react";

const Dashboard = ({UserStore}) => {
    console.log(UserStore)
    return(
        <>
        </>
    )
}
export default inject('UserStore')(observer(Dashboard));
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked prototype `__proto__`?

MobX might (or might not, it is implementation detail) create proxy class to hold methods or other stuff.

Try to do `console.log(UserStore.__proto__)` or just `console.log(UserStore.increment)`